# iOS apps dont launch on macOS 12.5 with m1 pro

Tags: macos, ios-appstore, mac-appstore, apple-silicon

I am running macOS Monterey 12.5. I am not able to open any of the iOS apps that I previously installed on my m1 pro MacBook pro (the apps worked fine previously). When I click the icon for one of these apps, absolutely nothing happens. No dock icon, no warning, nothing. I uninstalled & reinstalled the apps, and I restarted my mac. However, the same behavior is still exhibited. How to fix it?

Comment: What does the Console tell you?

Comment: Non-fatal error enumerating at <private>, continuing: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “PlugIns” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSURL=PlugIns/ -- file:///private/var/folders/wq/6n594_hs53vg37vqlwp5n95c0000gn/X/F358978C-BA51-5A48-81AA-0D7E8708A6D1/d/Wrapper/Hubitat.app/, NSFilePath=/private/var/folders/wq/6n594_hs53vg37vqlwp5n95c0000gn/X/F358978C-BA51-5A48-81AA-0D7E8708A6D1/d/Wrapper/Hubitat.app/PlugIns, NSUnderlyingError=0x15174bb00 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Security Policy is the problem.

- It needs to be on Full or Reduced.
- If it is set to Permissive then iOS apps won't launch and there will be no error message other than the cryptic text in Console log.

You can set the Security Policy using the recovery mode GUI on an M1 Mac.

Comment: @MattSephton You might want to take the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour) It is an aim of this site "Our goal is to have the best answers to every question, so if you see questions or answers that can be improved, you can edit them." Also comments are temporary and will often be deleted their reason to exist is to help the editing of answers. If the meaning is changed then yes unedit but not it probably means that your original meaning is not clear to some people.

Comment: @mmmmmm sure, I get it, I'm not new here. The edit added a section of all new content totally unrelated to my answer. You can check the edit log, ignoring the mess I made of rolling it back. Imagine you wrote a recipe for an apple tart, and then somebody edited it adding an extra paragraph with a recipe for chicken soup. Akin to vandalism. I've received negative points as thanks for trying to keep this answer on topic and accurate, which doesn't seem fair.

Comment: Why downvoted? This answer timestamp should be kept into consideration. A couple of months before the accepted answer! Conditions changed, essentially this is similar to accepted answer -permissions. No need to downvote. Folks will stop answering questions.

Answer (score -1):

Check with the App Developer and their Privacy Policy. The App is trying to access something which it is no longer entitled to do. Also check Activity Monitor. See if any Thread or Process is Killed when you launch the app. You might need to give specific permissions , which is not advisable.

Comment: It happens with every iOS app i install on my mac, so i dont think its a dev thing

Comment: try: create a new user, login and try to run one of the iOS apps. Next you could [start your Mac in Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mh21245/mac) and check. That’s just exclude any interference by some program etc. running in the back. Additionally try to repair the disk permissions using Disk Utility.

Comment: @slartibartfast none of these work. The "plugins" dir at that path seems to be nonexistent

Comment: Why downvoted? This answer timestamp should be kept into consideration. A couple of months before the accepted answer! Conditions changed, essentially this is similar to accepted answer -permissions. No need to downvote. Folks will stop answering questions.

Answer (score -2):

Starting from 12.4 (the first one on which I checked) and now with 12.5, it seems that you can only run **some** iPadOS apps on M1/M2 Macs.
They don't scale properly, nor do they respect rotation, etc. tried on a couple and it was the same on both.

Would be more than happy to have better news but this is the state of things at the moment it seems.

Comment: That as been true for all apple silicon macos. In my case have not noticed any changes in ios apps over the versions

Comment: I dont think this is correct because yes, i know only certain ios apps work. And im fine with the lack of rotation. With 12.5, those previously working ios apps (still on the store) stopped working.

Comment: I can still install and run apps that show "designed for ipad, not verified for macos" and I'm on 12.5.1